# php ajax call from class returns an empty array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, class

I am calling functions with ajax POST and then trying to access objects in class, but for some reason i am getting an NULL after calling an class function

Here is my code

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../db/_mysql.php';
include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../class/door.php';

$db = new _mysql();

if (isset($_POST['door'])) {
    if ($_POST['door'] == 'get-default') {
        $doors = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['amount']; $i++) {
            array_push($doors, array(
                'door-id' => $i,
                'panel-colors' => 'valkoinen'
                )
            );
        }
        order_door::setDoors($doors);
    }

    if ($_POST['door'] == 'get-doors') {
        print_r(order_door::getDoors());
        $doors = order_door::getDoors();
        if ((int) $_POST['total-count'] > count($doors)) {
            echo $_POST['total-count'] . '>' . count($doors);
        } else if ((int) $_POST['total-count'] < count($doors)) {
            echo $_POST['total-count'] . '<' . count($doors);
        }
    }
}

class order_door {

    private static $doors;

    public static function getDoors() {
        return self::$doors;
    }
    public static function setDoors($array) {
        if (count($array) == 0) {
            self::$doors = array();
        } else {
            self::$doors = $array;
            print_r(self::getDoors());
        }
    }

}
```

in second ajax call i am trying to access to get-doors
in POST get-doors print_r(order_door::getDoors()); is not printing anything. Any ideas?

Comment: where is your ajax request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is what must happen , you didn't have any data in

```
private static $doors;
```

So you set it in one ajax request and call it in another will reset it to default.

To fix this behavior you have to save this data to SESSION for example .

Comment: That is a pretty good idea to store my array into SESSION. Why wasn't I thinking that =P Thanks! But just wondering is it possible to do with ajax as well.. or is it reseting the array to null everytime